# How to give Error when one extension is for two voIp in asterisk

Tags: linux, asterisk

I have one server of asterisk I want to Create one Extension and I want when two 
voIp ( **3cxPhone** or **eyebeam** ) to connect to this Extension Give me **error**

Comment: Questions must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Tell us what you've tried to do, why it didn't work, and how it should work.

Answer (score 1):

you can't prevent this but By restricting which IP addresses can access each user in the sip.conf file you can limit allowable requests to a reasonable set of IP addresses.  This can be done by using permit= and deny= in the sip.conf file.

Comment: Please explain More detailed .